# How to display a javascript variable in option tag

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I need to display a variable that is declared in a javascript script in an option block. There will be one to two more select blocks that are dependent on the option selected in this block.

```
    <select name="expiration_year" id="expiration_year" onchange="populate(this.id,'expiration_month','expiration_day')">

    <script>
    //variable declaration in JavaScript
    var year =  new Date().getFullYear();
    </script>

    //I want to display the variable stored in "year" where it is marked in the 
    //following code
    //this <option value=year> is using the variable correctly, the second 
    //half of the line isnt using the variable (which should have a value 
    //equaling the current year)
    //instead it simply says year
    <select>
    <option value=year>year</option>
    <option value=year+1>year+1</option>

    </select>
```

[Image of what current code produces when run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tGGUe.png)

Any help at all would be greatly appreciated, i'm *extremely* new to coding web pages and using java script. I'm sorry if this question has already been asked and answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just add your options dynamically.

e.g.

```
// This assumes that this is the only select element on the page.
// Also, this would have to run in a script block 
// after the select element is added to the page.
var select = document.querySelector('select');
select.options.add(new Option(year));
select.options.add(new Option(year + 1));

// etc.
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! What my ultimate goal is, is the have a total of three selects on the page. with the order of dependence being year==> month==> day. with year month and day being the name of the selects. I've updated the question to reflect that there will be multiple selects. Thanks again!